# Extracting Carbon offset projects from website using beautiful soup and getting nothing

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract the data from this website('https://alliedoffsets.com/#/profile/2). It has many such projects and I want to get the values of Estimated Average Wholesale Price and Estimated Annual Emission Reduction. When, I trying to print the code using beautiful soup it is not giving those tags and giving empty values. I know it could be a basic thing but I'm stuck. May be the data is getting populated on the website using javascript but I cannot figure out a way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://alliedoffsets.com/#/profile/1'
r=requests.get(url)
url=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')

tab=soup.find("thead",{"class":"sr-only"})
print(tab)
```

Comment: Hi. You're right, if you look at the raw HTML downloaded from that URL, the page is rendered in JavaScript. You will need something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to parse the rendered HTML page.

Comment: Any links for suggestion? I'm badly stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page is rendered in JavaScript so the HTML elements cannot be extracted directly using BeautifulSoup. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) can be used to extract the rendered HTML then search for elements by ID, class, XPath, etc.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import re

url = 'https://alliedoffsets.com/#/profile/1'

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

# web driver goes to page
driver.get(url)

# use WebDriverWait to wait until page is rendered

# find Estimated Average Wholesale Price
elt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'direct-price-panel'))
    )
# extract just the price from the text
print(re.sub(r'.*(\$\S+).*', r'\1', elt.text))

# find Estimated Annual Emission Reduction
elt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[strong[contains(., 'Estimated Annual Emission Reduction')]]")
print(elt.text.split(":")[1])
```

Output:

```
 $5.06
 11603 tCO2
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded via JavaScript from external URL. To load the data using `requests`/`json` module you can use this example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://carbon-registry.herokuapp.com/1.0/provider/1"
params = {
    "embedded": '{"provider_capital_types":1,"provider_capital_types.capital_type":1,"provider_countries":1,"provider_countries.country":1,"contacts":1,"contacts.office":1,"provider_currencies":1,"provider_currencies.currency":1,"provider_languages":1,"provider_languages.language":1,"offices":1,"offices.country":1,"provider_sectors":1,"provider_sectors.sector":1,"provider_social_medias":1,"provider_social_medias.social_media":1,"provider_provider_types":1,"provider_provider_types.provider_type":1,"provider_stats":1,"provider_stats.stat":1,"provider_descriptions":1,"provider_descriptions.description":1,"relationships":1,"relationships.description":1,"provider_statuses":1,"provider_statuses.status":1}'
}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer 8hCH4MuPCa5t6ra8wtAz8xOQfJdjLvDVZk07ib60TZ"}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

stats = {s["stat"]["name"]: s for s in data["provider_stats"]}

print(f"{stats['Estimated Direct Price']['value']=}")
print(f"{stats['Estimated Annual Emission Reduction']['value']=}")
```

Prints:

```
stats['Estimated Direct Price']['value']=5.0630778182036105
stats['Estimated Annual Emission Reduction']['value']=11603
```

Comment: How did you convert the url into the herokuapp.com?

Comment: @Asad If you open Firefox developer tools (or in Chrome) - Network tab you will see all requests the page is doing. One of these requests if this URL with the data.

Answer (score 0):

The website is dynamic. So you can follow the next example selenium with bs4 to grab right data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://alliedoffsets.com/#/profile/1' 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
                            
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
driver.close()

Price = soup.select_one('p#direct-price-panel').contents[1].strip().replace('/tCO2e','')
Reduction= soup.select('.panel')[-1].contents[1].strip().replace('tCO2','')
print('Estimated Average Wholesale Price: '+ str(Price))
print('Estimated Annual Emission Reduction: ' + str(Reduction))
```

**Output:**

```
Estimated Average Wholesale Price: $5.06
Estimated Annual Emission Reduction: 11603
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works!